# LDAP authentication apache 2.2 error 500

Tags: authentication, ubuntu, apache2, ldap

This is my LDAP configuration in Apache2.2.x

```
  Order deny,allow
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Test"
  AuthBasicProvider ldap
  AuthLDAPURL "ldap://dc1.domain.com:389/DC=domain,DC=com?sAMAccountName" NONE
  AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com"
  AuthLDAPBindPassword "secret"
  authzldapauthoritative Off
  require valid-user
```

When i load the page i get the pop up for password en username.
But when i fill them in i get an internal server error.

If i look in the error log of apache is see no new errors.
If i change my BindPassword to something wrong i get errors in my /var/log/apache2/error.log

Pulling my hair out!

Comment: You search base (dc=domain,dc=com) doesn't look like it matches your bind DN (dc=agiledss,dc=local).

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, but in my default file it is right

Comment: 500 is what the client sees. You need to look at the server side logs. Off topic.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set "REFERRALS off" in /etc/ldap/ldap.conf.

Comment: Try it why? Mere guesswork is not an answer, and neither is unexplained voodoo.